# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus on product space

Tags: complex-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification

I wanted to check whether my proof is correct, since I did not use one of the hypothesis.

> **Proposition:** Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a measure space, $\Omega=\text{int } \Omega\subset \mathbb{C}$ and $f: X\times\Omega\to\mathbb{C}$ be such that $(\forall x \in X)\quad f(x,\cdot) \in L^1, (\forall z\in\Omega) \quad f(\cdot,z)$ is holomorphic. Suppose there exists a $g \in L^1$ such that $(\forall z \in \Omega)\quad |\partial_z f(\cdot,z)|\leq g(x)$. Then $F:\Omega\to\mathbb{C}$, $F(z):=\int f(x,z) d\mu(x)$ is holomorphic and $F'(z) = \int\partial_zf(x,z)d\mu(x), \quad (\forall z \in \Omega)$.

**Proof:** Let $w,z \in \Omega$, $w \neq z$, and $x\in X$. By the Mean Value Theorem, there exists $\theta = \theta(x)\in L_{wz}$, such that $$f(x,w)-f(x,z)=(w-z)\partial_z f(x,\theta)$$ where $L_{wz}$ is the line segment connecting $w$ and $z$.

Hence, $$\frac{\int f(x,w)-\int f(x,z)}{w-z} = \frac{\int f(x,w)-f(x,z)}{w-z} = \frac{\int(w-z)\partial_z f(x,\theta)}{w-z} = \int\partial_z f(x,\theta).$$

Taking the limit as $w \to z$, we have $\theta \to z$, and therefore $$F'(z) = \int\partial_z f(x,z)d\mu(x).$$

Comment: You haven't assumed that $\Omega$ is convex...

Comment: You also might want to revisit mean value theorem for holomorphic functions.

Comment: You are right. The proof is wrong, thanks.

Comment: Hint: use a different form of Mvt or the differential quotient, and open balls are convex.